# How to permutate all possible tree structure for fixed number of leaf for binary expression tree?

Tags: algorithm, tree

How to permutate all possible tree structure for fixed number of leaf for binary tree?
which algorithm to build all possible tree structure?
What is the number of all possible tree structure?

for binary expression tree, alphabet must be leaf

for example (a+b)*c

```
                        *
                      +   c
                    a   b
```

the number of leaf is 3

we want to permutate to other structure such as

```
                   *            
                 a   +   
                    b  c
```

I guess to fix the order, the same order because i will permutate the operator node in later process. Just expect the structure. the number of operator node is dynamic

if you want to challenge more, you can use dynamic order
i also want to know dynamic order algorithm

now try to fix the order first

one more constraint i notice is that every internal node should have left and right leaf

Comment: Could you please explain more about your problem.

Comment: Does the leaves have to be in the same order for each structure? (As in your example.)

Comment: I guess to fix the order, the same order because i will permutate the operator node in later process. Just expect the structure. the number of operator node is dynamic

Comment: I believe that tag genetic-algorithm is wrong for this question.

Comment: @Avinash, imagine a game where you're given several input numbers and one output number. Your task is to find an arithmetic expression whose result is as close to given output number as possible. See this page for the game in one Serbian quiz: http://www2.slagalica.tv/game/mojbroj

Comment: How genetic algorithm promise result the same in every round without permutate all possible tree structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My idea is recursively swap left and right node at each level except the leaf and save at each swap
I do not know whether is correct but i feel no missing